# How to make myself def class act as array in ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
class Heap
  attr_accessor :a, :heap_size
  def initialnize(a, heap_size)
    @a = a
    @heap_size = heap_size
  end
end
a = [16, 14, 10, 8, 7, 9, 3, 2, 4, 1]
a = Heap.new(a, a.length-1)
```

what should I do? Then I can aceess 16 use a[i],etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use inheritance:

```
class Heap < Array
  attr_accessor :heap_size
  def initialize(a, heap_size)
    @heap_size = heap_size
    super(a)
  end
end
a = [16, 14, 10, 8, 7, 9, 3, 2, 4, 1]
heap = Heap.new(a, a.length-1)
heap[0]
# => 16
```

Comment: In fact I prefer Mittag' answer.It's more clear.On the contrary,inheritance may behave unexpect.But thank you too.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Heap
  attr_accessor :a, :heap_size
  def initialize(a, heap_size)
    self.a, self.heap_size = a, heap_size
  end
end

a = [16, 14, 10, 8, 7, 9, 3, 2, 4, 1]
a = Heap.new(a, a.length-1)
```

Why don't you just try it? Ruby will help you :-)

```
a[0]
# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #<Heap:0x007f8516286ea8>
```

See? Ruby is telling us exactly what method we are missing:

```
class Heap; def [](i) a[i] end end

a[0]
# => 16
```

Comment: I just find answer in <Programming in ruby>.Anyway,Thanks a lot.I'm a newbee in ruby.There is a lot of question I will ask in the future.Thanks again in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want brackets, then

```
class Heap
  def [](n)
    # Retrieve value from nth slot
  end

  def []=(n, value)
    # Set value to the nth slot
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank u too.I prefer Mittag' ans.